# NSCFString _forgetDependentConstraint unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my application when I click my `RightBarButtonItem` it pushes another view controller but it shows the following error.

```
-[__NSCFString _forgetDependentConstraint:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x74c5960

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString _forgetDependentConstraint:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x74c5960'
```

I don't know the mistake what I did.

but in that view controller I put only this code in `viewDidLoad` 2nd view controller

```
            [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:TRUE animated:YES]; 




        first view controller contains the following code

        - (void)viewDidLoad
        {
            [super viewDidLoad];

            [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:TRUE animated:YES];
        baseView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 416)];

            UINavigationBar *navBar1 = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
            UINavigationItem *navItem1 = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@""];
            [navBar1 pushNavigationItem:navItem1 animated:NO];
            UIBarButtonItem *menuButton1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                                            style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                           target:self
                                                                           action:@selector(toggleMenu1)];
            navItem1.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton1;
            [baseView.self addSubview:navBar1];
            UIImageView *backgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"scr2.png"]];
            [baseView.self addSubview:backgroundImage];

            UIPanGestureRecognizer *pancontrol = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                           initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panLayer:)];
            [self.view addGestureRecognizer:pancontrol];

            topView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 416)];

            UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
            UINavigationItem *navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@""];
            [navBar pushNavigationItem:navItem animated:NO];
            UIBarButtonItem *menuButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Menu"
                                                 `enter code here`                         style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered                                                                  target:self
                                                                          action:@selector(toggleMenu)];
            navItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton;
            UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add"
                                                                          style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                         target:self
                                                                         action:@selector(toggleAdd)];
            navItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
            [topView.self addSubview:navBar];
            backgroundImage1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"notebookbg.png"]];
            [topView.self addSubview:backgroundImage1];
            [baseView.self addSubview:topView];
            [self.view addSubview:baseView];
                }
```

these are my code .

how to move from this first view controller to next view controller.

Comment: Where are you calling this method `_forgetDependentConstraint` ???

Comment: If it breaks after it pushes, then it's crashing after your `viewDidLoad` and possibly in `viewDidAppear` or somewhere similar. Do you know what line it's breaking at?

Comment: hi please paste some mote code...

Comment: am not calling this method _forgetDependentConstraint any where i my app

Comment: make breakpoint,,,,and say where did you have problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be with AddNewNote class. As Cocoanetics suggested, create a category on NSString and implement `_forgetDependentConstraint`: in the category. Add `#import` for new category header in `.PCH` file

Answer (score 1):

sounds to me like you are not properly assigning an actual NSString to one of the title or text properties of either the first or second view controllers.

For finding out where the problem occurs do this:
- implement a debug category on NSString and add a _forgetDependentConstraint: method that contains nothing but a breakpoint.
- When execution breaks on this method inspect the call stack to see where exactly it is breaking
- also inspect self inside the method and check what string is the culprit.

It sounds to me as if you have an NSString somewhere in your view hierarchy instead of a UIView. UIView subclasses have this _forgetDependentConstraint: method, but strings don't.

Comment: where i need to put this method.. in the first viewcontroller or 2nd?  -(IBAction)_forgetDependentConstraint:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"");
}

Comment: i dont understand what i need to do. i need more clear. because am new to this development

Comment: Add a new category on NSString, for example calling it Debug. Add a _forgetDependentConstraint: method to it. Add an NSLog into it. Set a break point onto this line.

Comment: like NSString *forgetDependentConstraint=[[NSString alloc]init];

Comment: @ Cocoanetics is it like this... NSString *forgetDependentConstraint=[[NSString alloc]init];

Comment: If you provide me the source code and steps to reproduce I'll find the problem and write a nice article on my blog for you to follow. You find my address on my blog http://www.cocoanetics.com.